# Some devices suddenly don't work

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Woke up, Win 7 would let printer work (Canon MP730) but not its SCAN function.
DVD R/W player/burner spins up but does not read. So I can't re-install from my discs!
One repair program says Registry entries for the DVD unit are either missing or corrupt, but how do I find out how to fix them and with what values?

Downloading new drivers?  Win 7 issues error message:  intall FAILED.  But it doesn't  say HOW to install them.

DVD reader WILL read Win 7 install disc, but...it only tries a restore point (no help) and 1 or 2 other things but no help.

I have bought and tried half a dozen malware, virus, and spyware removal programs:  nohelp.  I am about to try a etotal clean reinstall of Win 7 but fear it will wipe out ALL my existing programs and data.  Have hired a PC pro, paid $100 for 3 hours of useless labor.

There are either missing files, corrupt files, or files that override the "real" files. Can you recommend anything? Short of buying a new Hard Drive, and just reinstalling every program....and moving needed data over.  but if moved data contains hidden problems.....what then?

Comment: Step 1: Don't Panic. Have you run a `chkdsk`? Have you then run `sfc /scannow`? Once you've answered those questions (with appropriate results), more help will definitely be forthcoming.

Comment: You shouldn't put your email address in questions. People aren't supposed to help you via email, they're supposed to help you here. Getting help via email completely defeats the purpose of the site.

Comment: how much free disk space do you have on the system drive? Some of those problems are classic errors of running out of/low on space.

Answer (score 1):

I would say do what Randolph Potter Suggested - including not to panic!

Go to an elevated command prompt and use the following two commands:

```
 chkdsk
```

To scan for problems on your hard drive.

```
 sfc /scannow
```

To see if there is any corruption in your Windows installation.

If both of these pass, I would say that you have two very common scenarios.

When was the last time you read a disk and when was the last time you scanned?

I wouldn't bother using scanner/multi fix type programs, they scare you more than problems they fix! I doubt this is a registry problem.

I am not sure why the scanner would stop working but I have seen it before with service packs or third party programs interfering.

If you scan by pressing a button on the scanner, try to instead start the scan from the computer. (or vica-versa)

If you can't scan at all then, go to [the website](http://www.canon.co.uk/for_home/product_finder/multifunctionals/inkjet/smartbase_mp730/index.asp) and download updated drivers. If after everything, it still does not work, you can always scan to a memory card and read that from your computer.

Next, as for the writer, if you do a lot of burning (or even if you don't), they can die all the time. Typically I would say the life of a well used drive (1 burn a week) is about 2-3 years. When they start to fail, you have all sorts of weird errors - some disks read, some don't, random burn jobs fail etc.

I hope this helps - and if you need any further guidance, please leave more feedback and I am sure you will get this resolved.